# Understanding tokens in C# using %%

Tags: c#

I have a piece of C# that looks like this:

```
public static string PopulateLayoutHTML(string layoutHTML, RollupItem rollupItem, WebPartSettings settings, int itemIndex, string lastGroupByValue) 
{ 
    layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%ITEM_INDEX%%", itemIndex.ToString()); 
    layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%TITLE%%", rollupItem.Title); 
    layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%SUBTITLE%%", rollupItem.Subtitle); 
    layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%DESCRIPTION%%", StripDivTags(rollupItem.Description)); 
    layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%AUTHOR%%", rollupItem.Author);  

    if (!rollupItem.GroupByValue.IsNullOrEmpty() && rollupItem.GroupByValue != lastGroupByValue && layoutHTML.Contains("%%GROUPBY%%")) 
    { 
        layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%BEGIN_GROUPBY%%", "").Replace("%%END_GROUPBY%%", "").Replace("%%GROUPBY%%", rollupItem.GroupByValue); 
    } 
    else if (layoutHTML.Contains("%%BEGIN_GROUPBY%%")) 
    { 
        int startIndex = layoutHTML.IndexOf("%%BEGIN_GROUPBY%%"); 
        int endIndex = layoutHTML.IndexOf("%%END_GROUPBY%%") + 15; 
        try 
        { 
            string groupBySubstring = layoutHTML.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex); 
            layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace(groupBySubstring, ""); 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        layoutHTML = layoutHTML.Replace("%%GROUPBY%%", ""); 
    }
```

Could someone explain what all the names with %%These%% are for and what the code is doing?  How could these %%tags%% conceivably interact with a front-end UI that is HTML based?  The HTML also references them.

This is the layouthtml that the code is referencing :

```
<div style="border-bottom:solid 1px #009581; padding:5px; margin-right:10px;"> 

         <div style="width:100%; height:25px; margin:2px 0 0; width:100%; padding-bottom:5px;"> 
        <!--accordion head start--> 

             <div style="float:left;"> 

                <a href="javascript:showTaxRollupItem('%%ITEM_INDEX%%');" id="taxRollupExpand_%%ITEM_INDEX%%" style="display:inline;"><img border="0" src="/Style%20Library/Rollup%20Web%20Part%20Files/images/icnAdd.png"></a> 

                <a href="javascript:hideTaxRollupItem('%%ITEM_INDEX%%');" id="taxRollupContract_%%ITEM_INDEX%%" style="display:none;"><img border="0" src="/Style%20Library/Rollup%20Web%20Part%20Files/images/icnSubtract.png"></a> 

            </div>  

<div style="float:left; width:95%; padding-left:5px"> 

                %%BEGIN_LINKTAG%% style="color:#005293; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;" 

                %%CLOSE_LINKTAG%%%%TITLE%%%%END_LINKTAG%%&nbsp;(%%MODIFIEDDATE%%)%%SECURITY_ICON%% 

            </div> 

        </div><!--accordion head end--> 


        <div id="taxRollupDesc_%%ITEM_INDEX%%" style="margin:3px 0 10px 0; display:none;"> 
            <!--accordion content start--> 

            <p style="margin:3px 0 10px 15px; font-size:12px;"> 

            %%DESCRIPTION%% 

</p> 

        </div><!--accordion content end--> 


    </div>
```

What I'm actually trying to do is Group some fields in a SharePoint display web part.  That question is actually here, but I wasn't getting any responses posting ALL the information.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148776/group-by-fields-displayed-in-a-custom-web-part

I believe I should be adding some of these group by tags somewhere in my layout, but I'm not sure where.

Thanks for everyone's help so far.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the contents of `layoutHTML`.

Comment: There is no magic here. These are totally normal string replace calls.

Comment: layoutHTML is some sort of template containing `%%TAGS%%` which are replaced by values from rollUpItem. This is a common scheme/method for populating values in a template, but implemented in this way is not efficient ... you should parse one character at a time and replace `%%TAGS%%` as you find them, then you only walk the layoutHTML once.

Comment: This looks like some kind of templating mechanism. The HTML contains these variables (`%%NAME%%`) - this is the template. To create a concrete instance of the HTML page from that template, the variables are replaced in the method you show us.

Answer (score 2):

These are simple string token replacements. The server is taking a HTML template in a string, and simply replacing various tokens in it with values provided in the rollupItem object.

As far as HTML and C# go, the %% means nothing - it's being used by the developer because it's unlikely that %% would exist anywhere in a HTML document normally.

For example, if they'd used `TITLE` as the token, instead of `%%TITLE%%`, it's possible that the HTML could contain the word TITLE and it would incorrectly be replaced.

Comment: I updated the original question with some more details, if that helps put some perspective to it.  I'm new to C#

Comment: Thanks.  Now I get what the tags are supposed to be doing.  Is the code that uses any of the "group by" tags actually effective in grouping data on a page?  (SharePoint)

Comment: Not that I can see, though I don't know much about SharePoint.